# How to include jQuery.min.js in static web project of eclipse

Tags: jquery, eclipse

I have created one static web project using eclipse, juno. Inside webcontent folder i created one index.html file as below :
     This is the html file in which jQuery script is imported.I created one folder "lib" parallel to webContent and placed "jquery-1.10.2.min.js".When I am trying to run the html file in eclipse browser , jQuery feature is not working.

```
<head>
<script src="/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style type="text/css">
#box{
background:red;
height:100px;
width:100px;
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $('a').click(
        function(){         
            $('#box').hide(5000);       
        }
    );
}
);
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="box"></div>
<a href="#">Click me</a>
</body>
```

Kindly tell me if i am missing something.

```
Thanks.
```

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "jQuery feature is not working."

Comment: @AxelAmthor "jQuery feature is not working." means that if i am loading this html file in browser and then trying to click on anchor tag,it should hide the red color box which is not happening.

Answer (score 1):

Move the jQuery file in to the particular folder where index.html is and change

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

instead of

```
<script src="/lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I tried the approach suggested by you but its not working i.e. on click on anchor tag , box is not hidden.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see your folder structure but try moving the lib directory containing the jQuery file into the root of the webcontent folder.

You could also try changing the jQuery import to:

```
<script src="lib/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I am presuming that by "jQuery feature is not working" you mean that the page is failing to find the jQuery file.

Comment: "jQuery feature is not working." means that if i am loading this html file in browser and then trying to click on anchor tag,it should hide the red color box which is not happening.

Comment: Folder structure of my project is as follows : static web project ->webcontent folder and lib folder ->index.html in webContent folder and jquery-1.10.2.min.js in lib folder.

Comment: Have you tried moving the lib folder into the webcontent folder and changing the script import as above?

Comment: If i am moving lib folder inside webcontent folder , project is showing me error sign i.e. small red cross on jquery-1.10.2.min.js